# query mysql from bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

So I need to read in a bunch of ID numbers from a file and do a mysql query on each of them. I started off with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="eidlist.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    mysql --host <redacted> --user <redacted> --password=<redacted> -N -e "use netops;select m_mailname from footprints where m_empno=$line;"
done <"$file"
```

This works and produces the expected output. Now I need to do the same thing but with a different list of IDs, querying a different field. Since the field I'm now querying on contains alphanumeric values (whereas the previous one was entirely numberic), I need to surround the value in quotes in the mysql query string, which I escape with \" like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="pidlist0.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    mysql --host <redacted> --user <redacted> --password=<redacted> -N -e "use netops;select m_mailname from footprints where m_stuid=\"$line\";"
done <"$file"
```

This doesn't work - the script produces no output. What am I doing wrong?

When I test the mysql command at the command line (with the $line variable pre-populated to one of the values from the file), it works, but when run from inside the script it produces no output. What's going on?

Comment: pls give exact mysql command that was ok in your commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Just use  m_stuid='$line';"  ?  Or change the double to single.

Comment: With the first suggestion, it still produces no output, presumably because with single quotes the variable doesn't get expanded, so it's literally searching on "$line", which produces no results. With the second suggestion, each line errors out with "ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\"'.", which I don't understand.